# smarty capture {foreach} results in empty variable

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

Smarty version 2
if I capture a static string :

```
{capture name=test}
 a huge page or string can go here
 {/capture}
```

I can simply use {$smarty.capture.test} to dump my captured string in both my current template or in a child template no problem

If I try capture a "{foreach}" loop like:

```
 {capture name=test}
  {foreach item=Row from=$DataGrid.Rows name=RowsGrid}
    ,['{$Row.DataCells.project_name.Data}', {$Row.DataCells.approved_budget.Data}]
{/foreach}
 {/capture}
```

I can use it easily in the current template like:

```
   {$smarty.capture.test}
```

and it displays the correct data as a string.
however when I try use it in a child template :

```
 {include file='/full/path/child.tpl'}
 {$smarty.capture.test}
```

it will result in empty captured data like:

```
  ,['', ] ,['', ] ,['', ]
```

if I use {$smarty.capture.test|var_dump} it shows as "string(86)" 
what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming in your last sample that `child.tpl` fills the test variable, and you then try to use it in the including template afterwards. [Given how Smarty handles scope](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variable.scopes.tpl) the empty output is completely right - scope inherits only downwards. A parent cannot access variables set by its child.

Apparently using the variable directly in a filter bypasses the scope checks, which would certainly be a bug in the implementation. Then again, Smarty 2 is years old, [v3 has been with us for years](http://www.smarty.net/v3_overview) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) is far more practical in the HTML5 age.

Comment: I suppose my tenacity is a result of this statement:
"This means you can use all variables from the including template inside the included template"
taken from:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl

I don't really have the luxury of swapping template engines at this time so I am stuck trying to get variables from one template into another.

So to be clear: are you saying that it is not possible and the fact I can get a static variable passed from a child.tpl is a bug?

Comment: The statement you quote is correct: scope inherits *downwards*, you can use variables from the *including* template (ie. the parent) in the *included* template (child.tpl). The other way around is not intended and could lead to dramatic effects. It does seem like a bug to me.

Comment: The issue I am facing is I have a "Dashboard" which for lack of a better term I called a "parent". the dashboard displays a series of google charts, there are 6 charts each with it's own template.

I am trying to get all 6 charts on this one "Dashboard" page. so using the "downwards" scope how would I go about this, thoughts?

Comment: I don't see the issue with what you describe, would need to see more of the code. But I don't do free consultancy  :)

Comment: I'm not asking for "free consultancy" I am simply trying to describe the situation. thanks for your input, have a good day.

Comment: I understand, and I have no problem with that. I'm here to fix 'puzzles' and help people. Once the followup questions come too big or complex though I have learnt to draw the line, many people expect to get their entire code written for them on SO. I didn't want to imply you were one of them, I just indicated that looking further into the issue would cost me an amount of time that would justify an invoice.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me without a problem:

PHP file:

```
$smarty->assign('data', array(
        array('name' => 'a1'),
        array('name' => 'a2'),
        array('name' => 'a3'),
        array('name' => 'a4'),
        array('name' => 'a5')
    ));
$smarty->display('normal.tpl');
```

`normal.tpl` file:

```
{include file='child.tpl'}
{$smarty.capture.test}
```

`child.tpl` file:

```
{capture name=test}
    {foreach item=Row from=$data}
        ,['{$Row.name}']
    {/foreach}
{/capture}
```

Output for this is as expected:

```
,['a1'] ,['a2'] ,['a3'] ,['a4'] ,['a5']
```

You should make sure that you have your variables assigned correctly and if it's not the case you should provide more details.